# SVG data not displayed in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

I create a image with javascript and include the url to the .svg by path. IE10, Firefox 28 display the SVG without errors as wanted. But in IE11 it is not displayed. The console message says, that

> SVG4601 SVG data are in a wrong format and cannot be fully analized

The path TO the .svg in my img-folder is correct. The SVG file is this one:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
> <!-- Generator: Adobe Fireworks 10, Export SVG Extension by Aaron Beall (http://fireworks.abeall.com) . Version: 0.6.0  -->
> <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
> <svg id="" viewBox="0 0 10 7" style="background-color:#ffffff00" version="1.1"
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve"
>   x="0px" y="0px" width="10px" height="7px"
> >
>   <defs>
>       <linearGradient id="gradient1" x1="1513.3362%" y1="46.9992%" x2="1513.3362%" y2="99.9993%">
>           <stop stop-color="#ffffff" stop-opacity="1" offset="0%"/>
>           <stop stop-color="#e2e8e0" stop-opacity="1" offset="100%"/>
>       </linearGradient>
>   </defs>
>   <g id="Ebene%201">
>       <path d="M 8.8984 1.0115 L 5.1008 3.1196 L 1.1095 1.0239 C 0.9419 0.7588 0.5762 0.6707 0.2926 0.8281 C 0.0092 0.9849 -0.0842 1.3271 0.083 1.5928 L 4.5723 5.9756 C 4.6781 6.1431 4.8695 6.2476 5.0776 6.25 C 5.2856 6.2522 5.4797 6.1536 5.5903 5.9888 L 9.9084 1.6052 C 9.9703 1.5127 10 1.4102 10 1.3091 C 10 1.123 9.901 0.9419 9.7207 0.8359 C 9.4418 0.6719 9.0736 0.7498 8.8984 1.0115 Z" fill="url(#gradient1)"/>
>   </g>
> </svg>
> ```

And it is generated with the following JS:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = folder/filename.svg;
```

Any idea why IE11 cannot display this one / what is wrong with the path data?? THX

Comment: I tried it myself and it displays fine in IE11. Can you maybe make a fiddle or other test to show the problem?

Comment: You're missing string quotes in your JS sample: `img.src = "...";`

Comment: @Jeremy: the pathname already is a string (generated with `toString()` I already tested this - so path - names are recognized correctly..